# Table variable join equivalent in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, record

I'm given quite a huge table `My_Table` and a user-defined collection `Picture_Arr` as an input usually having 5-10 rows declared as:

```
TYPE Picture_Rec IS RECORD (
     seq_no                         NUMBER,
     task_seq                       NUMBER); 
TYPE Picture_Arr IS TABLE OF Picture_Rec;
```

In MS SQL I would normally write something like:

```
DECLARE @Picture_Arr TABLE (seq_no INT, task_seq INT)
SELECT M.*
FROM My_Table M
INNER JOIN @Picture_Arr A
  ON M.seq_no = A.seq_no AND M.task_seq = A.task_seq
```

But I can't get my head around how to re-write the same code in Oracle as `Picture_Arr` is not a table. As some tutorials state that I could've looped through `My_Table` and compare keys, but is it efficient in Oracle or is there another way of doing that?

Comment: Please, describe how do you get the data for `Picture_Arr` typed variable? T-SQL code snippet has no variable initialization, so it is not clear what should be joined and how to prepare the data for join.

Comment: What is it you really want to achieve? If you know the values and you can fill an array with them, why can't you just write a query with the related `IN` clause (`select * from my_table where (seq_no, task_seq) in ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))`)?

Comment: There's much going on, so I've simplified everything to simple `select` statement. Data for `Picture_Arr` is populated somewhere else and in fact there types are declared in a generated code. All I'm left with is function body template that returns another collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for. It is a bit complicated to understand what is the desired output, and whether the data of the record is stored somewhere or not

```
create type Picture_Rec as object(
seq_no                         NUMBER,
task_seq                       NUMBER); 
)
/

create type Picture_Tab as table of Picture_Rec
/

create or replace function get_picture_list
return Picture_Tab
is
  l_pic Picture_Tab;
begin
   select Picture_Rec ( seqno, taskseq )
   bulk collect into l_pic
   from your_table; -- the table you have these records
   return l_pic;
end;
/
```

Then you run

```
SELECT M.*
FROM My_Table M
JOIN TABLE ( get_picture_list() ) p 
  ON M.seq_no = p.seq_no AND M.task_seq = p.task_seq
```

Comment: I've missed a `TABLE` keyword in a `JOIN` clause!